# Is it possible to globally ignore "Error: Too few arguments to function"?

Tags: php, function, arguments, parameter-passing

I have several functions in my code, who require more than 1 arguments.

I was using PHP 5.5, and whenever I input only the first argument, it worked fine, and simply ignored the second argument (I guess it saw it as "0").

But I've just upgraded to PHP 7.2 and this has become an issue.

So instead of fixing all of my code, which is spread on multiple files, is there a way to order PHP 7.2 to keep treating undefined arguments as "0", in order to avoid this Error, which is causing the page to crash?

**EDIT:**

sample function:

```
function calculate( $m,$status ) {

    return ''.$m.''.$status.'';

}
```

if `$status` doesn't exist, it should simply output `$m`

Comment: The proper fix (probably) involves changing the _functions_, not the callers. You'd have to add default values to arguments that aren't always provided. This may be less work than you think—how many functions are giving you this problem?

Comment: Folks, PHP 4.3.x through 7.0.x issued a warning but PHP 7.1+ is issuing a fatal exception.

Comment: I would see setting default values for these arguments as part of upgrading to PHP 7.2. If it's too much work, then don't upgrade that far. Stricter typing is one of the best reasons for upgrading to 7.x IMO followed by performance.

Comment: You can upgrade as far as PHP 7.0.29 without needing to fix your code.

Comment: _Side note:_ You can change `return ''.$m.''.$status.'';` to `return $m . $status;`. The quotes aren't needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest and cleanest way is to provide a default value for each parameter, making them **optionals**:

```
function myFunction ($requiredParam, $optionalInt = 0, $optionalStr = '') {
    //
}
```

then you can call `myFunction(1);` or `myFunction(1,2);` `myFunction(1,2,'x');` without errors.

If you're curious about [why this happens](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.incompatible.php), it's beacuse

> "Previously, a warning would be emitted for invoking user-defined
>   functions with too few arguments. Now, this warning has been promoted
>   to an Error exception. This change only applies to user-defined
>   functions, not internal functions."

Comment: Thank you. didn't know it was possible.

Comment: @rockyraw ;) glad to help